# core packages get removed by apt-get update & dist-upgrade

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1 of my `Quantal` machines (that I upgraded from `Precise` just yesterday), `apt-get dist-upgrade` wants to remove following packages that are I believe included in `desktop-full`. Anybody has an idea why?

```
ros-groovy-{ bfl, bullet, common-rosdeps, orocos-kinematics-dynamics, physics-ode, resource-retriever, robot-model-tutorials, ros, rosbag, rosunit, rqt-console, rqt-plot, rqt-py-common, timestamp-tools }
```

Commandline output:

```
iuser@btt:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Ign http://packages.ros.org quantal InRelease
Hit http://packages.ros.org quantal Release.gpg     
Hit http://packages.ros.org quantal Release      
Hit http://packages.ros.org quantal/main amd64 Packages 
Hit http://packages.ros.org quantal/main i386 Packages
Ign http://packages.ros.org quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.ros.org quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ros-groovy-bfl ros-groovy-bullet ros-groovy-common-rosdeps ros-groovy-orocos-kinematics-dynamics ros-groovy-physics-ode
  ros-groovy-resource-retriever ros-groovy-robot-model-tutorials ros-groovy-ros ros-groovy-rosbag ros-groovy-rosunit
  ros-groovy-rqt-console ros-groovy-rqt-plot ros-groovy-rqt-py-common ros-groovy-timestamp-tools
The following packages have been kept back:
  libboost-all-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev
  libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-math-dev libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-program-options-dev
  libboost-python-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-serialization-dev libboost-signals-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-test-dev
  libboost-thread-dev libboost-wave-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 14 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
After this operation, 25.5 MB disk space will be freed.

isaito@btt:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ tree
.
├── google-chrome.list
├── google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
├── google-chrome.list.save
├── google.list
├── google.list.save
├── irie-elisp-precise.list
├── irie-elisp-precise.list.distUpgrade
├── irie-elisp-precise.list.save
├── openrave-release-precise.list
├── openrave-release-precise.list.distUpgrade
├── openrave-release-precise.list.save
├── precise-partner.list
├── precise-partner.list.distUpgrade
├── precise-partner.list.save
├── puppetlabs-precise.list
├── puppetlabs-precise.list.distUpgrade
├── puppetlabs-precise.list.save
├── ros-latest.list
├── ros-latest.list~
├── ros-latest.list.distUpgrade
├── ros-latest.list.distUpgrade~
├── ros-latest.list.save
├── ros.list
├── ros.list~
├── ros.list.distUpgrade
├── ros.list.save
    
iuser@btt:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ more ros-latest.list
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu quantal main
iuser@btt:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ more precise-partner.list
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner #Added by software-center
iuser@btt:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ more precise-partner.list.distUpgrade
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner #Added by software-center. # Disabled manually after upgrade to quantal
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner # Added manually after upgrade to quantal
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52327/core-packages-get-removed-by-apt-get-update-&-dist-upgrade/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-15**:
My guess is something doesn't fit together anymore dependency-wise and you'd probably be able to re-install groovy after the update. No guarantees, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed this. As @dornhege indicated, in my case `libboost-iostreams` was somehow broken and I forced to upgrade it (via `synaptic`, not necessarily so though).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0